# What are some use cases for the Application Log (BC-SRV-BAL)

Tags: abap

Hello fellow developers,

I recently stumbled upon the Application Log and find it to be quite handy. Now I am wondering, from a best practice perspective, what are some use cases for utilizing the Application Log vs. normal messages / class based exceptions?

Comment: To be able to compare the Application Log with something, could you precise to what medium you output the "normal messages / class based exceptions" ? (ALV screen, job log, spool file, text file, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application log comes in handy to

- **store messages.** Interactive messages and exceptions are lost after the user clicks them away. The application log stores that information for longer periods of time.
- **log background processes.** These have no direct means to inform a user because there *is* no user, only some other process that triggered the batch.
- **provide additional details.** Interactive messages are usually minimized to not spam the user with too many popups. The application log can provide additional aspects and side infos to accompany the main result.
- **log "undercurrents".** If a reuse component is unsure what level of detail its consumer wants, it can write an application log with high level of detail that the consumer later can consume or not, as desired.

It is not appropriate when

- you want to process the logged details in an automatic way. Application logs are for display to the end user. Application processing should store or hand over data in a more appropriate format.
- you need to process vast amounts of data. Writing the application log is fast, but takes time for the database roundtrips, such that large numbers of records can slow down the actual application too much.
- you need to store sensitive data. Application logs are secured with authorization checks, but still they may not be the appropriate place for really sensitive information.

Answer (score 2):

Normally application log is used when end-user need not be informed of this information. Application log complements the normal messages and class based exceptions but not completely replace them.

Imagine a situation, there is an issue with data on a background processing. If a developer want to see what is the data that was being processed (after it is processed), it will be difficult. A developer can thus write some data to application log based on his gut if there is a possibility of failure.

Normally, this application logging is controlled by some user parameters and also the granularity of the data that is being stored in application log.

Hope this helps.